# How to exclude legend for a particular plot with multiple plots using scale_color_manual in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I am trying to plot multiple plots using ggplot2 in R.

I would like to set manual color pallette and exclude geom_line and geom_point with data_1 in scale_color_manual. Is there a way I can do it?

```
#named set of colors
color_set <- random_color_generator(interaction(x$col1, x$col2))

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = data_1, mapping = aes(x= period, y = value, group = interaction(col1, col2)), size = 0.5, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(data = data_1, mapping = aes(x= period, y = value, group = interaction(col1, col2)), size = 2, shape = 1, stroke = 0.2, , show.legend = F) +
  geom_line(x, mapping = aes(x = period, y = value, color = col1), size = 1.3) +
  geom_ribbon(data = x_ribbon, mapping = aes(x= period, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), color = "dimgray", alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = color_set)
```

When I use the above code, I get below warning and every line in the graph becomes black.

```
Warning message:
Removed 64 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

I tried all the parameters available in scale_color_manual() like na.translate, na.values and drop but nothing seemed to help. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Adding the data structure of data_1 and x

```
#x
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   64 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ col1    : Factor w/ 1 level "model1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ col2    : Factor w/ 4 levels "scenario1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ region  : Factor w/ 1 level "world": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 1 level "var_1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ unit    : Factor w/ 1 level "billion Rs/yr": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ period  : int  2005 2010 2015 2020 2025 2030 2035 2040 2045 2050 ...
 $ value   : num  5 10 13 17 20 ...

#data_1
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1114 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ col1    : Factor w/ 25 levels "model_x","model_y",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ col2    : Factor w/ 177 levels "scenario1","scenario2",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ region  : Factor w/ 1 levels "world",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 1 levels "var_1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ unit    : Factor w/ 1 levels "billion Rs/yr",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ period  : int  2005 2010 2015 2020 2025 2030 2035 2040 2045 2050 ...
 $ value   : num  6 10 11 15 23 ...
```

x_ribbon is computed like below.

```
x_ribbon <- x %>% select(period, value) %>%
              group_by(period) %>%
              summarise(ymin = min(value), ymax = max(value))
```

color_set is a named vector like below

```
model1.scenario1             model1.scenario2             model1.scenario3             model1.scenario4 
    "#E41A1C"                    "#377EB8"                    "#4DAF4A"                    "#984EA3"
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset. You have several datasets, post samples of them.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic I have added the description. Please check.

Comment: From your example data we are still lacking the `x_ribbon` data and the `random_color_generator` function.

Comment: I have added the necessary details. Kindly help.